# Choose load balancer for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing

When I worked with Java I used NGINX as load balancer, but now we have Windows technology stack and Windows Server 2008R2 as server PS. Now we need to choose load balancer.

I wanted to use nginx for windows, but my colleague says that nginx is effective only on Linux systems. It really true about nginx? What balancer is good for use on Windows servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some info about using nginx on Windows. We had a problem with the nginx max connections limit: by default, nginx for Windows has a limit on 1024 connections per core. But we can rebuild nginx and increase that parameter. So we are continuing to use nginx.